# Extract XML From Sentence C#

Tags: regex, xml, parsing

I am looking for away to extract XML content from a sentence, for example:

---

This is my next destination:

```
<Destination>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <City>Washington</City>
</Destination>
```

I will take `<Airline>Qatar</Airline>` on `<DepartureDate>01 January 2018</DepartureDate>`.

`<mailto:a@a.com>`

---

What is the best way to get the XML content from the sentence using RegExp in C#? Beside hard code the tag as part of the pattern? Or is there any XML Parser that are able to parse the XML from the content?

The result that I need to achieve will be:

```
<Destination>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <City>Washington</City>
</Destination>
```

and

`<Airline>Qatar</Airline>`

`<DepartureDate>01 January 2018</DepartureDate>`

but without `<mailto:a@a.com>`

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser?

Comment: @Marathon55     The XML is embedded inside a sentence. For example: Part of email content and I need to extract out these XML from the email. The string contains non XML contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
string input = "My next destination is <Destination><Country>US</Country><City>Washington</City></Destination> and I am taking <Airline>Qatar</Airline> on <DepartureDate>01 January 2018</DepartureDate>. <mailto:a@a.com>";

string pattern = "<(\w+)>.*?</\1>";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks. Another questions: under the same scenario, any idea what is the best way to check that every open tag, must contains its close tag? What I can think of is to run two separate Regex. One to get all open tag and another Regex to get all close tag. After that compare the MatchCollection result.

Comment: You can get the tags that don’t have a closing tag by using  `string pattern = "<\w+>(?!.*?</\1>)"`

Comment: Thanks! It works! But i have to go with running RegEx twice because I cannot find the pattern to match XML tags with close tag but without open tag. I tried `(?!<\1>.*?)</(\w+)>` but does not seem to work.